# Como retirar um trecho de um texto em especifico de um PDF com o Python

Tags: python, pdf, texto

Olá, estou precisando extrair um trecho especifico de um PDF. A ideia é achar as inscrições estaduais que foram baixadas no diário oficial do estado onde eu moro, isso é para a coleta de dados para a criação de um TCC. Por isso estou criando um código para que ele possa abrir o PDF e pegar as inscrições estaduais.
O pdf contem sempre a palavra chave "inscrições estaduais baixadas" e depois vem o número dela, a ideia é que o número seja extraido.

por enquanto consegui fazer esse código:

```
import PyPDF2 as p2

pdf = open('DOEAL-25_09_2020-COMPLETO.pdf', 'rb')

pdf_reader = p2.PdfFileReader(pdf)

n = pdf_reader.numPages

for i in range(0, n):
    print('Página {}'.format(i+1))
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
    if page.extractText() != "":
        conteudo = page.extractText()
    else:
        print("image")
    with open("teste_de_pdf.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as arq:
        arq.write(conteudo)
```

Com ele estou conseguindo ler o PDF e importar o conteudo dele para TXT, mas queria filtrar o conteúdo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o módulo `re`

```
import re

texto = """inscrições  estaduais baixadas
123456 pag 32.1
lore inscrições estaduais baixadas 123123 gj  inscrições estaduais
 baixadas 111111  quam efficitur dignissim. Nam non 222 tortor
nisl. inscrições estaduais baixadas 777777  Vivamus sit amet
number: 2  felis sit amet leo mattis inscrições estaduais baixadas
666666"""

print(re.findall(r'baixadas\s(\d+)', texto))
# > ['123456', '123123', '111111', '777777', '666666']
```